# Not Able To Install Jupyterthemes

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

```
C:\Users\KIRAN>conda install jupyterthemes
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible so
lve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible so
lve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current cha
nnels:

  - jupyterthemes

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
# install jupyterthemes
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes

# update to latest version
conda update jupyterthemes
```

Comment: Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: You could have added the link to the [source](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) of this answer